# Is there a way to return null on a custom InputSelect in blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to add search functionality to a page on my blazor server app to allow users to search by true, false or both. Initially had it as a string InputSelect but now that I come back to it I want to change it to a neater solution, so I'm trying to make a custom input select to inherit from InputSelect that will have 3 allowed values: true, false and null. I'm trying to bind it to a bool? parameter in my search model class called isVegetarian.

At the moment the line stating "result = null;" gives an error because "cannot convert null to type parameter 'TValue'. Is there a way I can return null in this function? Or is there a better way to go about what I want to do?

Here is the attempt at making a custom bool? InputSelect:

```
// Start of code

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RecipeManager.Web.Shared
{
    public class CustomNullableBoolInputSelect<TValue> : InputSelect<TValue>
    {
        protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out TValue result,
            out string validationErrorMessage)
        {
            if (value.ToLower() == "null")
            {
                result = null;
                validationErrorMessage = null;
                return true;
            }
            if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(bool?))
            {
                
                if (bool.TryParse(value, out bool resultbool))
                {
                    result = (TValue)(object)resultbool;
                    validationErrorMessage = null;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = default;
                    validationErrorMessage =
                        $"The selected value {value} is not a valid bool?";
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return base.TryParseValueFromString(value, out result,
                    out validationErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is where it's called from:

```
<div class="col-12 row">
    <label class="col-6">Vegetarian</label>
    <CustomNullableBoolInputSelect class="form-control col-6" @bind-Value="searchModel.isVegetarian">
        <option value="null" selected>All</option>
        <option value="True">Vegetarian</option>
        <option value="False">Not Vegetarian</option>
     </CustomNullableBoolInputSelect>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind to a nullable : `bool?`.

```
<EditForm Model=@someModel>
    <InputSelect @bind-Value=@someModel.SomeValue>
        <option value="">Null</option>
        <option value="true">True</option>
        <option value="false">False</option>
    </InputSelect>
</EditForm>

[@someModel.SomeValue.ToString()]
[@(someModel.SomeValue == null)]

@code {
    SomeModel someModel = new SomeModel();

    class SomeModel
    {
        public bool? SomeValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, as I said, searchModel.isVegetarian is nullable bool (bool?).